# Multivariate function composition

Tags: elm

Let's consider the following:

```
f: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
f a b c = a + b + c

g: Int -> Int
g x = x * 2
```

now, I'd like to create a composed function like

```
f(g(a), g(b), g(c))
```

how to use `<<` and `>>` operators to achieve that? Is it even possible to compose multivariadic functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multivariadic does not really exist in Elm. Best I can suggest is

```
f : Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
f a b c =
    [ a, b, c ] |> List.map ((<|) g) |> List.sum


g : Int -> Int
g x =
    x * 2
```

Note that you had an error in the type signature for g

Comment: Corrected, good point - as every function is curried (as I understand). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> how to use << and >> operators to achieve that? Is it even possible to compose multivariadic functions?

Yes, easily:

```
h = flip flip g << ((<<) (<<)) << ((>>) g) << f << g
```

`h` is a `<function> : number -> number -> number -> number`, which is the same as `h a b c = f (g a) (g b) (g c)`.

I think we don't need to dig deep in the correctness, since it's obvious that the version with arguments is much more readable.

Comment: Note that `flip` was removed from `elm/core` in 0.19, so I'd be very hesitant to accept this as a proper solution! /s

Comment: thanks for the note about `flip`. my point in the answer is that it's possible to compose the functions in order to achieve the desired result, but it makes no sense since the code becomes less readable than straight solution

Comment: Yeah, I got that, and I'm actually pretty impressed you managed (and bothered) to figure it out. Hence the (easily missed) "/s" to indicate sarcasm on my end ;)

Comment: So practically it's possible but there's no point of doing so... Thanks for the answer :).